What makes the frequency resolution of the DCT double that of the DFT?
I'm trying to understand the mathematical basis for why the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) is said to have twice the frequency resolution of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). Can someone explain how this is derived and what advantages this higher resolution offers compared to DFT (especially in audio and image compression?)
Thank you for your insights!

Useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq7YgjbVrPg. The DCT does NOT have higher frequency resolution. It provides N real coefficients vs the DFT giving N/2 complex coefficients, so its the same information amount. Interpreting this as a higher resolution isn't really appropriate.
